# AInsert Block in AcadTable

Tags: autocad, cad, objectarx

I need to insert an `AcadBlockReference` into `AcadTable`, but i've got an error with the block `ObjectId` property.

```
//*****************Sample Code*************************************  
AcadApplication gbl_app = null;  
AcadDocument gbl_doc = null;  
AcadLayout presentacion = null;  
AcadTable tablaAcad = null;  

gbl_app = (AcadApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application");  
gbl_doc = gbl_app.ActiveDocument;  
object AC_entidad = new object();  
object basePnt2 = null;  

gbl_doc.Utility.GetEntity(out AC_entidad, out basePnt2, "Seleccione objeto:");  
AcadBlockReference objBlock = (AcadBlockReference)AC_entidad;  
bloqueId = objBlock.ObjectID;   

double[] vertices = new double [3];  
vertices[0] = 49.24;  
vertices[1] = 155;  
vertices[2] = 0;  


tablaAcad = gbl_doc.ActiveLayout.Block.AddTable(vertices, 4, 2, 3, 10);  
tablaAcad.SetCellTextHeight(0, 0, 2);  

tablaAcad.SetTextHeight(5, 1.5);  
tablaAcad.SetColumnWidth(0, 5);  
tablaAcad.SetColumnWidth(1, 50);  

tablaAcad.SetBlockTableRecordId(3, 0, bloqueId , true);
```

ERROR: Not valid class

Answer (score 0):

`bloqueId` is the object ID of the specific block reference picked by the user. `SetBlockTableRecordId` needs the ID of the block definition in the drawing's block table. These are completely different types (classes), so that's what the error message means.

The `Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.BlockReference` class has a `BlockTableRecord` property that returns the object ID you want. My recommendation would be to redo your code to use those native C# classes everywhere instead of the `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop` (COM) classes you're currently using.

If you can't change to native classes for some reason, then the best I can find is that the `AcadBlockReference` class you are using exposes a `Name` property that is the block name, and you should be able to look up the block definition ID from the block table.